# Joining Multiple Tables While Showing Correct COUNT and SUM Data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a pretty complex query I need to do which requires data from 6 different tables. The tables look like this:

Table 1

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | first_row |

Table 2

| id | table1_id | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 | 8 |

Table 3

| id | table1_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |

Table 4

| id | table3_id | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 |

Table 5

| id | table4_id | count |
| --- | --- | --- |

Table 6

| id | table5_id | count | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

And I basically want to collect the count and sums from each of the table into 1 row such as:

Result

| table1_id | table1_name | SUM(table2_count) | SUM(table4_count) | SUM(table5_count) | SUM(case when table6.status = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) | SUM(case when table6.status != 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Tables 5 and 6 are empty

This is the latest thing I have tried, I hope it is clear:

```
SELECT table1.*, COUNT(distinct tbl3.id), SUM(table2.count::int), (SUM(table2.count::int) - SUM(table4.count::int))
, COUNT(table5.count), COUNT(table6.count)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON (table1.id = table2.table1_id AND table2.deleted_at IS NULL)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT distinct table3.id, table3.table1_id, table3.deleted_at,
    SUM(table4.total_count::int),
    COUNT(case when table6.status != 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),
    COUNT(case when table6.status = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
    FROM table3
    LEFT JOIN table4 ON (table3.id = table4.visa_id AND table4.deleted_at IS NULL)
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT table5.id, table5.table4_id,
        COUNT(case when table6.status != 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        COUNT(case when table6.status = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        FROM table5
        LEFT JOIN table6 ON (table5.id = table6.table5_id AND table6.deleted_at IS NULL)
        GROUP BY 1
    ) tbl3 ON table4.id = table5.table4_id
    WHERE table2.deleted_at IS NULL
    GROUP BY 1

) tbl2 ON (table1.id = tbl2.table1_id AND tbl2.deleted_at IS NULL);
```

The result I get based on the data added on top and the above query:

| table1_id | table1_name | SUM(table2_count) | SUM(table4_count) | SUM(table5_count) | SUM(case when table6.status = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) | SUM(case when table6.status != 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first_row | 3 | 32 | 18 | 2 | 2 |

I do not get any errors but all the count come out wrong, either doubled or tripled and sometimes completely wrong (not even just doubled or something).

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: Aggregate before you join, so you don't cause a Cartesian explosion

Comment: I added the latest statement I tried in the question and it inludes GROUP BY on each statement

Comment: This would be a lot clearer with sample data and expected results, [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your current SQL seems invalid.  Please show the `create table` statements.  Make sure you've run this exact SQL and it produces the given result in the question.  Make sure you include the constraints (primary/unique keys, etc). That impacts this issue (functional dependence).  There are other issues as well.

Comment: There are too many errors in the SQL to guess.  In this case, it's probably better to just reduce the problem to a minimal example that exhibits the count problem.  There's really no need to introduce all these unrelated mistakes, when your basic issue is about very simply join behavior.  This kind of question is duplicated over and over in SO.  Please forget/remove all the derived tables (subqueries) and just focus on simple joins between some t1, t2 and t3.

Comment: The program is for a multi-step process that tracks the count of something in these different steps. I managed to get the solution which is to get the SUM or COUNT once which is inside the LEFT JOIN, then in the parent query which uses the LEFT JOIN, I just write it without any SUM or COUNT again.